# How to get all instances of a component in an React app and valid its proprs using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Suppose I have a component called **Personnel**, and it has a prop **gender**. In Jest, is it possible to pull all instances of this component in my React app and valid that they all have gender to be either male, female, or in-between?

This is helpful for me to put an extra layer of protection against people trying to add something that is not valid / does not exist for a given prop.

Code below only gives a warning:

```
gender: PropTypes.oneOf(['male', 'female', 'in-between'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [findWhere](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/findWhere.html):

wrapper.findWhere(n => n.name() === 'Personnel' && (n.prop('gender') === 'male' || ...))

Comment: Is it possible to search the whole <App /> that has routing?